# Cannot import from public folder in CSS Create React App

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, create-react-app

In a project bootstrapped with Create React App, in my `public` folder I have a `assets` folder with the file `logo512.jpg`.

When I reference the file in a component like so

```
<div>
    <img src='/assets/logo512.jpg'/>
</div>
```

I everything works perfectly. However, when I reference the same file in a CSS file for the same component like so:

```
background {
    background-image: url('assets/logo512.jpg');
}
```

Then the error `Can't resolve '/assets/logo512.jpg' in DIRECTORY_OF_COMPONENT/assets/logo512.jpg`

Note that DIRECTORY_OF_COMPONENT is not the public folder but the folder the CSS file is in. How do I make it so the url references the public folder instead?

Below is the full code along with my file structure:

```
// HomePage.js

import React from 'react';
import 'tachyons';
import './HomePage.css';

function HomePage() {
    return (
        <div className="background tc">
            <div>
                <img src='/assets/logo512.jpg'/> //this works 
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default HomePage;



// HomePage.css
.background {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: url('/assets/logo512.jpg'); //this does not work
}
```

[image: File Structure]

Comment: You may try my answer, I have mentioned in detail how to do this :) If you still have issues I would like to check you folder structure

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**

**CASE 1:**

If you image is in the public folder. Then the code should work provided you are using `assets` folder right within the `public` folder.

**Codesandbox Demo for all the three cases :** https://codesandbox.io/s/images-not-loaded-hkzq1

**CASE 2:**

In case you want to use images from other than the `public` folder, You will need to import the image in your React project first. (Make sure the Path is correct and your image).

```
import MyImage from "./assets/logo512.jpg"
```

And then use in the `src` attribute.

```
<img src={MyImage}/>
```

**Case 3:** When using CSS to set image on a block level element:

```
.background  {
  height:200px; /* Make sure height of the div is given for image to be within*/
  background-image: url("assets/logo512.jpg");
}
```

This should work properly (provided you relative path is correct with regard to the CSS file)

**NOTE:** With SVG images React has come up with a component based way where we use  as a component by importing our SVG with `ReactComponent`.

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';

return(<Logo/>)
```

Comment: My issue is that I have case 3 (with the image in public/assets and the url in the css), but the error is still present.

Comment: My code is (I believe - unless I am missing something) identical to case 3 of your demo

Comment: Let me check is there anything missing in your code :)

Comment: One reason: You need to set the height of your div first :) Check this May be this is the issue. Have updated my answer in case 3

Comment: I've edited the question with the relevant code and file structure. I'll hold off on closing the question for now since my issue is still present :)

Comment: Have patience... Just use ./assets/logo512.jpg  or assets/logo512.jpg

Comment: background: url('assets/logo512.jpg'); I mean remove / from the url inside

Comment: I've already tried both of those, they produce the same result.

Comment: Instead of setting height in  % try px for now

Comment: Try some like this :) I will tell you why this might be happening.

Comment: height: 200px;
  background: url("assets/logo512.jpg");
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: Also no change - my issue is with the URL anyway. The compiler is referencing the path the CSS file is in rather than the public folder.

Comment: Can you create on sandbox project for this...Or wait...I will show it with the components that you have

Comment: tachyons what is this library used for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227075/discussion-between-cirrus86-and-imran-rafiq-rather).

Comment: Case 1 and 2 are not relevant to the question, which is how to use the folder within **CSS**.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue myself but found the other answer too vague.

To be clear: `assets` in your CSS corresponds to the `src/assets` dir in your project.

Here's me using a static asset in my CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "ITC Clearface";
  src: url("assets/ClearfaceStd-Regular.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

But you can also diagnose why your path isn't working from the error the compiler shows, eg:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assets/somefile' in '/home/mike/Code/myapp/website/src'

See if that file exists by running (bash or powershell)

```
ls /home/mike/Code/myapp/website/src/assets/somefile
```

**If that doesn't work, then the file doesn't exist - you likely have a typo in the name!** In my case it turns out the font file I was using in my CSS had a minor spelling error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i do it and works pretty fine: it is two ways:

1. I import that image from public, and i do it in tsx components like this:

```
const myBg = './images/bg.png';
// and then use this variable where ever i want: like this: 
<div style={{backgroundImage: `url('${myBg}')`}}< /div>
//remember to set width and height on that div , to display image inside
```

2. Import it directly from public to css, by hard coding the full path:  like:

```
    .my_bg{
        background-image: url('../../../public/images/bg.png') /* this is a full path to public from your css/sass , and
     the rest of your CSS ... */

}
```